# Start Acitvity from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listview

I got my `MainActivity(FragmentActivity)` with `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` which creates `OrdersFragment` in which i have `ListView`. Now i want to start new Activity `OnItemClickListener` but i can't figure out how to do this.

This is `OrdersFragment` class:

```
public class OrdersFragment extends Fragment {

ListView lv;
private ArrayList<Order> d = new ArrayList<Order>();
private ordersAdapter adapter;

public OrdersFragment (){

}

public OrdersFragment setArguments(ArrayList<Order> orders){
    if(adapter == null) return this;
    adapter.setData(orders);
    Log.d("fragment", "zmiana");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return this;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //d.add(new Order());
    Log.d("fragment", "orders fragment created" + d.toString());
    lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders_list, container, false);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(itemClicked);
    adapter = new ordersAdapter(inflater, d);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

    return lv;
}

public ArrayList<Order> getOrders(){
    return d;
}

OnItemClickListener itemClicked = new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Log.d("fragment", "clicked!!" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        startActivity(new Intent(OrdersFragment.this, OrderActivity.class));
    }
};
}
```

It says that Intent constructor is undefined and also when i move over startActivity it says `Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.` And it states that this fuction is defined in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity` but I'm acually import this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pass context as `getActivity()` to `intent`

```
 OnItemClickListener itemClicked = new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Log.d("fragment", "clicked!!" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), OrderActivity.class));
        }
    };
```

Comment: omg it works... but I'm 100% sure i have tested this before when i was searching - maybe I did some typo. Probably need to get some sleep today...

Answer (score 0):

In `Fragment` we have to pass context as `getActivity()`, replace your code with this below code it will work.

```
OnItemClickListener itemClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       Log.d("fragment", "clicked!!" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
       startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), OrderActivity.class));
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OnItemClickListener itemClicked = new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if(getActivity() != null) {
            Log.d("fragment", "clicked!!" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), OrderActivity.class));
        }
    }
};
```

getActivity() will give you the Activity context that you can use to start the new Activity. In some rare cases getActivity() can return null so checking getActivity() is not null might not harm in your case.